# Show property form json object with angular http

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an object like this:

```
export interface CameraNodeValue { 
    readonly id?: number;
    readonly dt?: string;
    readonly countUp?: number;
    readonly countDown?: number;
}
```

and I try to get from endpoint the value from the property countUp

So this is how I subscribe in component on service:

```
 cameraNodevalue: Array<CameraNodeValue> = [];

 showLineChart() {
    this.sensorNodeService
      .cameraDataInInterval(2, '2021-01-18 00:00:00', '2021-01-30 23:59:00', '1')
      .pipe(
        map((data=> data['countUp'].map(obj => {

          return {
            countUp: obj.countUp
          }
        }))))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('chart', data);
      });
  }
```

But I get this error:

```
core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

So what I have to change?

Thnak you

ahh,
oke Yes, I get this back:

```
0:
count_down: 2
count_up: 2
dt: "2021-01-18T08:28:00Z"
id: 2
```

So but when I do this:

```
showLineChart() {
    this.sensorNodeService
      .cameraDataInInterval(2, '2021-01-18 00:00:00', '2021-01-30 23:59:00', '1')
      .pipe(
        map((data=> data['count_up'].map(obj => {

          return {
            countUp: obj.countUp
          }
        }))))


      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log('chart', data);
      });
```

I still get this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Comment: **1.** Are you sure the response contains the property `countUp`? Try to do a `console.log(data)` inside the `map` to verify. **2.** `countUp` is defined as a number. Number does not contain the method `map`.

Comment: Agree with Michael, just put ```tap``` inside the pipe and watch the values.

Comment: I guess `data` is an array. So do `data.map((obj: any) => { return { countUp: obj.count_up } })`

Comment: @fridoo. Thx. I only have to update the model.

Comment: But how to get only the value from the propertie? So without the name: countUp

Comment: `data.map((obj: any) => obj.count_up)`

Comment: if you put as answare I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is an array. Use `data.map((obj: any) => obj.count_up))` to get an array with the `count_up` values from every object in `data`.

```ts
showLineChart() {
  this.sensorNodeService
    .cameraDataInInterval(2, '2021-01-18 00:00:00', '2021-01-30 23:59:00', '1')
    .pipe(
      map(data => data.map((obj: any) => obj.count_up))
    )
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log('chart', data);
    });
```